# Magento 2 - price calculation for different currencies

Tags: magento2, multicurrency, currency-rates

I use two different currencies on my Magento 2 shop - DKK and SEK.
I have two different website Danish and Swedish, with DKK as base currency for Danish website, and SEK as base currency for Swedish website.

I've set currency rate to 1 DKK = 1.28 SEK.

All products have only one price which is DKK in admin.

How ever, I need to use DKK (instead of SEK) as base currency for the Swedish website. And when I do this, the price on the front-end (swedish site) is wrong, it multiplies the currency rate 1.28 twice. how does this happened? and Where in the code should I change if I want to force the system to only multiply the currency rate once?